# Wordpress-read/write access via FTP

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress

I'm currently having an issue with a Wordpress install I have.  The theme which was installed is under user Apache rather than my username & so currently I can't edit any files inside that directory.  How can I change it from Apache to my username?

Answer (score 1):

Contact your hosting provider, explain your problem and they should sort it out for you.